# How does minecraft generate biomes in 1.17

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to know how the Minecraft biomes in java edition gets generated with a specific script. Is there any type of script (maybe using `python`) that can display the biome in which the player is spawned in the world. So that i know the biome I am currently in

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to know what biome you are currently in, or information about the mechanics of biome generation?

Comment: @Hacker it is to know what biome I am currently in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any Python scripts to do so, and believe none exist - possibly Chunkbase's [biome finder](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder) uses one, but it's not available to the public. An open-source tool [Amidst](https://sourceforge.net/projects/amidst.mirror/) written in Java provides this functionality so this is the closest to what you seek.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! :)

Comment: @RiteshSathiyamoorthi Note: player's exact spawn position is randomized within a 21x21 square centered on world spawn (and re-rolled every time you spawn) so if the world spawn coincides with a border between two biomes, your spawn point biome will be random.

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up @SF

Answer (score 0):

You can know which biome you're in by pressing F3. If you want something more automated, probably check out @SF.'s answer.